# django ModelForm - this field is required error always shows

Tags: django, modelform

I have this in my views but why does it always show the error that the field is required

```
form = ProgressReportForm(request.POST or None):

return render(request, template, {'form': form})
```

Here is my form

```
class ProgressReportForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ProgressReport
        fields = ['title', 'report_progress']
        widgets = {
            'report_progress': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean, "it show the error that the field is required"? Are you saying that when you submit the HTML form generated by this ModelForm, your web page shows an error message about a field being required? If so, which field?

Comment: I'm sorry I think my wording i wrong. What I meant was once I go to the form, it immediately displays the error that the field is required

Comment: What is the exact text of the error message you receive?

Comment: This field is required. I think what happens is the form immediately submits itself before I even type my input